# what is better than if-statement when making a calculator

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm trying to create a program that calculates the price of the selected food while displaying the total price. I can already calculate and display the total price. My problem is whenever the user enters "[3] exit" and he chooses "[1] reset", the program breaks and detects many error. I wonder what better statement should I use with my program. Thanks!

```
void PriceCalculator(){
    system("cls");
    char yn[3];
    int choice;

    float spinachP=7.18;    
    float romaineP=12.21;
    float mustardP=11.18;
    float carrotsP=1.6;
    float potatoP=1.0;
    float yamP=2.1;
    float asparagusP=15.98;
    float brocolliP=10.65;
    float melonP=8.31;
    float strawberryP=10.62;

    float spinach=0;
    float romaine=0;
    float mustard=0;
    float carrots=0;
    float potato=0;
    float yam=0;
    float asparagus=0;
    float brocolli=0;
    float melon=0;
    float strawberry=0;

    float spinachT=0;
    float romaineT=0;
    float mustardT=0;
    float carrotsT=0;
    float potatoT=0;
    float yamT=0;
    float asparagusT=0;
    float brocolliT=0;
    float melonT=0;
    float strawberryT=0;

    float totalSpi=0;
    float totalRom=0;   
    float totalMus=0;
    float totalCar=0;
    float totalPot=0;
    float totalYam=0;
    float totalAsp=0;
    float totalBro=0;
    float totalMel=0;
    float totalStr=0;

    float totalP=0;

    do{
        border();
        gotoxy(50, 5); p("Budget Calculator");
        totalP=totalSpi+totalRom+totalMus+totalCar+totalPot+totalYam+totalAsp+totalBro+totalMel+totalStr;\                                                          
        gotoxy(50, 7); p("Total Price : P %.2f", totalP);
        gotoxy(5, 5); p("[1] Spinach\t=\tP %.2f", totalSpi);
        gotoxy(5, 6); p("[2] Romaine\t=\tP %.2f", totalRom);
        gotoxy(5, 7); p("[3] Mustard\t=\tP %.2f", totalMus);
        gotoxy(5, 8); p("[4] Carrots\t=\tP %.2f", totalCar);
        gotoxy(5, 9); p("[5] Potato\t\t=\tP %.2f", totalPot);
        gotoxy(5, 10); p("[6] Yam\t\t=\tP %.2f", totalYam);
        gotoxy(5, 11); p("[7] Asparagus\t=\tP %.2f", totalAsp);
        gotoxy(5, 12); p("[8] Brocolli\t=\tP %.2f", totalBro);
        gotoxy(5, 13); p("[9] Melon\t\t=\tP %.2f", totalMel);
        gotoxy(5, 14); p("[10] Strawberry\t=\tP %.2f", totalStr);
        gotoxy(5, 15); p("[11] Exit");

        gotoxy(5, 17); p("Enter Choice: ");
        s("%d",&choice);

    if(choice == 1){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("How many grams of Spinach? ");
    s("%f",&spinach);
    if(spinach < 0){
        gotoxy(5, 20); p("Error! Invalid input.");
    }else{
    spinachT=(spinach/20)*spinachP;
    totalSpi += spinachT;
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Price: P %.2f",spinachT);

    gotoxy(5, 21); p("Enter again (y/n)?");
    s("%s", &yn);
    if(strcmp(yn, "y")==0){
        system("cls");

    }else if(strcmp(yn, "n")){
        break;
    }

    }
    }
    else if(choice == 2){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("How many grams of Romain Lettuce? ");
    s("%f",&romaine);
    if(romaine < 0){
        gotoxy(5, 20); p("Error! Invalid input.");
    }else{
    romaineT=(romaine/20)*romaineP;
    totalRom += romaineT;
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Price: P %.2f",romaineT);

    gotoxy(5, 21); p("Enter again (y/n)?");
    s("%s", &yn);
    if(strcmp(yn, "y")==0){
        system("cls");

    }else if(strcmp(yn, "n")){
        break;
    }

    }
    }
    else if(choice == 3){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("How many grams of Mustard Greens? ");
    s("%f",&mustard);
    if(mustard < 0){
        gotoxy(5, 20); p("Error! Invalid input.");
    }else{
    mustardT=(mustard/20)*mustardP;
    totalMus += mustardT;
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Price: P %.2f",mustardT);
    }
    }
    else if(choice == 4){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("How many grams of Carrots? ");
    s("%f",&carrots);
    if(carrots < 0){
        gotoxy(5, 20); p("Error! Invalid input.");
    }else{
    carrotsT=(carrots/20)*carrotsP;
    totalCar += carrotsT;
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Price: P %.2f",carrotsT);
    }
    }
    else if(choice == 5){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("How many grams of Potato? ");
    s("%f",&potato);
    if(potato < 0){
        gotoxy(5, 20); p("Error! Invalid input.");
    }else{
    potatoT=(potato/20)*potatoP;
    totalPot += potatoT;
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Price: P %.2f",potatoT);
    }
    }
    else if(choice == 6){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("How many grams of Yam? ");
    s("%f",&yam);
    if(yam < 0){
        gotoxy(5, 20); p("Error! Invalid input.");
    }else{
    yamT=(yam/20)*yamP;
    totalPot += yamT;
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Price: P %.2f",yamT);
    }
    }
    else if(choice == 7){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("How many grams of Asparagus? ");
    s("%f",&asparagus);
    if(asparagus < 0){
        gotoxy(5, 20); p("Error! Invalid input.");
    }else{
    asparagusT=(asparagus/20)*asparagusP;
    totalAsp += asparagusT;
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Price: P %.2f",asparagusT);
    }
    }
    else if(choice == 8){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("How many grams of Brocolli? ");
    s("%f",&brocolli);
    if(brocolli < 0){
        gotoxy(5, 20); p("Error! Invalid input.");
    }else{
    brocolliT=(brocolli/20)*brocolliP;
    totalBro += brocolliT;
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Price: P %.2f",brocolliT);
    }
    }
    else if(choice == 9){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("How many grams of Melon? ");
    s("%f",&melon);
    if(melon < 0){
        gotoxy(5, 20); p("Error! Invalid input.");
    }else{
    melonT=(melon/20)*melonP;
    totalMel += melonT;
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Price: P %.2f",melonT);
    }
    }
    else if(choice == 10){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("How many grams of Strawberry? ");
    s("%f",&strawberry);
    if(strawberry < 0){
        gotoxy(5, 20); p("Error! Invalid input.");
    }else{
    strawberryT=(strawberry/20)*strawberryP;
    totalStr += strawberryT;
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Price: P %.2f",strawberryT);
    }
    }

    else if(choice == 11){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("[1] Reset [2] Back to Home");
    gotoxy(5, 20); p("Enter choice: "); 
    s("%d", &choice);


    if(choice = 1){
        totalP=0;

        spinachT=0;
        romaineT=0;
        mustardT=0;
        carrotsT=0;
        potatoT=0;
        yamT=0;
        asparagusT=0;
        brocolliT=0;
        melonT=0;
        strawberryT=0;

        totalSpi=0;
        totalRom=0;
        totalMus=0;
        totalCar=0;
        totalPot=0;
        totalYam=0;
        totalAsp=0;
        totalBro=0;
        totalMel=0;
        totalStr=0;

        system("cls");
    }

    else if(choice == 2){
        break;  
    }

    }
    if(choice < 1 || choice > 12){
    gotoxy(5, 19); p("Error! Please choose between 1-10.");
    }
    }while(choice != 0);
    }
```

Comment: As haccks already mentioned, a switch case or a if-else is better suited for your application. However, what do you mean with "the program breaks and detects errors"? I am getting the impression that you have another problem which has nothing to do with your user choice evaluation.

Comment: well im having problems breaking out of the if-statement inside if statement and going back to my main page. @jwsc

Comment: Post the actual code you're having issues with else we're just guessing.

Comment: I cannot help you with code outside of that what was posted here. I would like to see how you call your PriceCalculator() function, and how you currently do the exit.

Comment: @jwsc i already posted the actual code.

Comment: You need to avoid so many variable names.  You either need a structure type (which you probably haven't covered yet) or array types (or ultimately an array of structures).  You'll need the vegetable names in an array, and the amounts another array, and each of the other bits of information in its own array.  You find the position of the name in the array of names, and then index into the other arrays to find the relevant values.  You build up the screen image using the arrays. You do not write everything out 10 times — that way lies madness (as you have to remember to fix each bug 10 times).

Comment: Well your code is too long to perform such a simple task. It has too many errors. Some of them are pointed out in the aswers as well. In the

Answer (score 1):

Either use `if-else` or `switch` statement. Otherwise, each and every `if` condition will be evaluated and checked as per your snippet.

Comment: well you got a point, but sadly  My problem is whenever the user enters "[3] exit" and he chooses "[1] reset", the program breaks and detects many error the user press "[2] exit" it doesnt go back to the main page. thanks anyway. @haccks

Comment: well, my codes are running now. it can calculate and display the total price. my only problem is with the [3]exit.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code:

```
else if(choice == 11){
    // some code...
    if(choice = 1){ // you miss a "=" here!!!
        // more code...
    }

    else if(choice == 2){
        break;  

    }

}
```

Results in this:

```
if(choice = 1)
```

This will assign choice to 1 and after that it will check if choice is bigger than 0. This will be true all the time. the next branch

```
else if(choice == 2)
```

will never be executed.

PS: if you ask a question next time, Please include the correct and full description of the problem.

> the program breaks and detects many error

Is no description of a problem. 
Also, If you would have debugged the lines, or included some trace messages, you would have noticed immediately that your program flow is not as expected.